# Unhandled exception crashes nestjs server

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm new to Nest.js and building a REST API server.
And I'm also using typeorm, which has much async function.
If I miss await keyword when I use async function and got an exception like 'QueryFailedError', server emits exception and doesn't work anymore. (all request is rejected, socket hanged up).

If I add code snippet below, server works after exception occurs but function is not working as expected (like transactional event).

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

How can I deal with this problem? I want my server wouldn't stop when unhandled exception occurred without loosing functionality. like.. when a problem occurs that is not a matter of nest.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default for **all** node servers. If  there's an unhandled exception it **will** crash the server. As you've noticed, you can use `process.on('unhandledRejection')` and `process.on('unhandledException')` to handle the errors. Rather than handling them in global process events, you *should* be using `await` or at the very least `.catch`ing the promises so that you don't end up with these instances

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just suprised that server could be down in production environment because of an await  fault, Even without proper error handling. Then is there no way to switch context to nestjs or node when unhandled exeption is occurred?

Comment: You can set the [`--unhandled-rejectsion`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--unhandled-rejectionsmode) CLI variable for the `node` process to `warn` or `warn-with-errors` instead of `strict` or `throw` (default) to try and modify the behavior. This is Node's default behavior for a reason though, as you _should_ have your errors handled

Comment: Right. I definitely agree that the best way to handle this problem is just writing await keyword or handle exception when using promise. But someone could do a mistake and when it is released to production env, server just  could go to stop in unexpected. I’ll investigate what you recommended and do work more concisely. Thank you for your kind comment.

Comment: From this blog (https://blog.heroku.com/best-practices-nodejs-errors), I learned that this is intended result of nodejs. It would be good to start clean state when unhandled exception or promise occurs. I understand and the best way to dealing with this problem is careful programming and then clean start from unhandled event.